# How to disable the automatic updates notification in office Office 2010

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-office-2010

I am using **Office 2010**, i developed a small macro(in **Office 2007**) to merge worksheets content in a single worksheet. While trying to run the macro in 2010 a pop up comes in a sheet, which is requiring automatic updates option. So it blocks the macros to work properly. Is there any way to disable the automatic update option in Office 2010.

**Note** : Once i open the excel file it shows that **The work book contain links to the data sources[image: Could you please help me to remove this while opening the excel]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pop-up message shows that your excel document is linked to another spreadsheet, to keep the link you click update then you wont have a problem you will continue working on that spreadsheet, but it you want to remove the link on excel go to data from data click edit links then the pop up window will show which spreadsheet is linked to your spreadsheet, then click on breaklink, then it will remove the link

Comment: Thanks dude.... it worked :-) actually i didn't break the link but disabled the update check in that..

Comment: Hi Not dude, Lady

Comment: oopsss... am sorry dima... once again happy that you cleared my doubts soon.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In Win7, try:

Control Panel | Windows Update | Change Settings 
Remove the check next to "Give me updates for Microsoft prodcts ..." etc.

Not positive, but I think that might do it.

Comment: Sorry Steve already i have removed the check in that.